# Set-AzStorageBlobContent : Can not find the specified file

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cloud-shell

I am working on a PowerShell code that is expected to upload a JSON file to my azure Blob Storage.
My PowerShell code is saved in my local drive/folder and I am running that azue PowerShell CLI.
My PowerShell is falling on this command.

Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $containers -File "./test.json" -Context $ctx.

tried all like below
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $containers -File "C:/folder/test.json" -Context $ctx
or Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $containers -File "test.json" -Context $ctx

All are falling with the below error:

Set-AzStorageBlobContent : Can not find the specified file 'C:\folder\ManJason.json'.
At C:\folder\BlobUpload.ps1:23 char:5

- ```
  Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $containers -File "./ManJason ...
  ```
- ```
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-AzStorageBlobContent], ArgumentException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.SetAzureBlobContentComman
    d

My Environment :

{
"azure-cli": "2.17.1",
"azure-cli-core": "2.17.1",
"azure-cli-telemetry": "1.0.6",
"extensions": {}
}

Comment: Could you please share your PS code and path were you running your script?

Comment: $resourceGroupName="azureiotlabs"  
$storageAccName="iotstorage"  
Connect-AzAccount   
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Upload blob content.."    

    $storageAcc=Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccName  
    $ctx=$storageAcc.Context 
    $containers="blobcontainer"

    Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $containers -File 'C:\Coding Work\MyJason.json' -Context $ctx
Disconnect-AzAccount

Answer (score 0):

The command in your issue is correct. But the error shows that you could not get the file from the path. Plz change it with absolute path of your local file, like `C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\pic.jpg`.

```
$account_name ="pamelastorage123"
$account_key =""      
$container="pamelac"

$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $account_name -StorageAccountKey $account_key    

Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $container -File "C:\Users\peng\Desktop\pic.jpg"  -Context $context
```

[image]

---

Also tried the command in your comment:

[image]

Comment: I tried with everything fully qualified path like "C:\test\pic.csv" or ".\pic.csv" all are saying the same.

Comment: Hi, @user1431921. Have you tried to open the file in cmd.exe? And does it work?